# Distance between a point $x \in \mathbb R^2$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2 \le 4$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $S=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1^2+x_2^2\le 4\}$. Let $f(y)=\inf\{||y-x||:x\in S\}$. Find $f$ explicitly.

This is the $f(y)$  I got so far

$$\inf \left\{ \sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}:(x_1+x_2) \in S \right\}$$

How do I relate $f(y)$ with $x_1^2+x_2^2\le 4\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f (\mathrm y) := \max \left( 0, \|\mathrm y\|_2 - 2 \right) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } \|\mathrm y\|_2 \leq 2\\ \|\mathrm y\|_2 - 2 & \text{if } \|\mathrm y\|_2 \geq 2\end{cases}$$

---

#### Proof

The case $\|\mathrm y\|_2 \leq 2$ is trivial. If $\|\mathrm y\|_2 \geq 2$, the squared Euclidean distance between $\rm y$ and the disk is equal to the squared Euclidean distance between $\rm y$ and the disk's *boundary*, i.e., a circle of radius $2$.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm y - \mathrm x \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm x \|_2 = 2\end{array}$$

Note that

$$\begin{array}{rl} \| \mathrm y - \mathrm x \|_2^2 &= \| \mathrm y \|_2^2 - 2 \langle \mathrm x , \mathrm y \rangle + \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \\ &\geq \| \mathrm y \|_2^2 - 2 \| \mathrm x \|_2 \| \mathrm y \|_2 + 4\\ &= \| \mathrm y \|_2^2 - 4 \| \mathrm y \|_2 + 4\\ &= \left( \| \mathrm y \|_2 - 2 \right)^2\end{array}$$

where the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) was used. Hence, $$\| \mathrm y - \mathrm x \|_2 \geq \| \mathrm y \|_2 - 2$$

Comment: Thank you. I've seen you edited my question and removed Convex analysis and linear programming tags, why? .I'm taking a course of convex analysis and this exercise was homework from this course. Also this exercise is from  Linear programming book by Bazara.

Comment: @Anneliset. If it is homework, it should be tagged as such. This question has nothing to do with linear programming and little to do with convex analysis. It's a quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP).

Comment: okay. fyi there's no tag for homework :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $f(y)= 0 $ if $y\in S$ obviously. If $y\notin S,$ due to the symmetry of $S$ we have that $f(y)=(1-\lambda)\|y\|,$ were $\lambda$ is the greatest positive number such that $\lambda y \in S.$ We have $\lambda y \in S$ iff $\|\lambda y\|\leq 2,$ whcih results in $\lambda = \frac{2}{\|y\|}.$ Hence, you have

$$f(y)= (1-\frac{2}{\|y\|})\|y\|= \|y\|-2,$$ if $y\notin S.$

Comment: I think you mean $f(y)=||y||-2$ (as the radius is $2$ and not $4$).

Comment: Could you explain how did you get $f(y)=(1-\lambda)\|y\|$?

Comment: @Kuifje Yep, thanks. I will correct it.

Comment: @Anneliset. Think geometrically. $S$ is the circle with center at the origin and radius 2. Assume $y \notin S.$ Then the element $x\in S$ that minimizes $\|y-x\|$ is a point $S$ that is colinear with $y$ and the origin. Hence you will have $x = \lambda y $ for some $\lambda >0.$ Now you have $\|y-x\|=(1-\lambda)\|y\|.$ If you choose $\lambda $ big, but such that $\lambda y \in S,$ you minimize the function. Of course, this is no formal proof. You could use analytic geometry for this

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** Do this geometrically.  Visualize $S$ as a set on the Cartesian plane with coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$.  What does this set look like?  Then observe that $f(y)$, for any point $y$ in the plane, denotes the infimum (the greatest lower bound, in other words) of the distance from $y$ to any point in $S$.  That is to say, $f(y)$ is the length of the shortest line joining $y$ to $S$.

Can you give an explicit expression for the length of this line?

Comment: I think I visualize it. $y=m(x-x_1)+y_1$ where $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. Is correct?

Comment: How do I get the length?

Comment: @Anneliset. You're still thinking too algebraically. Think in terms of pure geometry.

Comment: @Anneliset.: Draw the line connecting $y$ to the nearest point in $S$.  Extend this line further—what interesting point does this line always go through?  (Actually sketch this out—don't just try to visualize it in your head.)

Comment: the center of the circle?

Comment: @Anneliset.: Exactly!  And what are the coordinates of the circle's center?